# Immutable.js not rendering list data

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-saga

My reducer looks like this:

```
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';
const GET_LIST = 'GET_LIST';

const initialState = fromJS({
  list: [{
         ID: 1
  },
  {
    ID: 2
}]
});

function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_LIST:
      return state
        .set('list', action.payload);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
export default reducer;
```

This is how my component looks like:

```
class App extends Component {

    render () {
        return ( 
        <div className="container">  
        <table className="table table-striped">

          <tbody >                          

              {this.props.list.map(item => {
                console.log('Item: ' + item.get('ID'))
                return (
                  <div>{item.get('ID')}</div>
                );
              })}
           </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProp = (state) => {
  console.log('state list: '+ state.reducer.get('list') );
    return {
      list: state.reducer.get('list'),
    }
  }
```

The issue is: I'm trying to loop through 'this.props.list', but it is not rendering data in my html page. But when i try to console.log the list, it is displaying data in the browser console, but data won't render in the html page. I want to show the initialState data in the page.

This is how it is displayed in the console:
[image]

Please anyone have a solution for this. I hope everyone understood the question.

Comment: have you tried `.toJSON()` ?

Comment: yes, i tried it. it doesn't work

Comment: if you console.log this.props.list in render method whats the output?

Comment: @Dayan `console.log('state list: '+ state.reducer.get('list').toJSON())` try this and see the console

Comment: it's prompting undefined

Comment: sry! it is displaying the object in my initialState array

Comment: @Dayan have you gotten what you wanted?

Comment: yes, but the issue is it's not rendering in the html page. i can get the value from the console.log.

Comment: inside the map returning part is not working?

Comment: @Dayan show the console inside render and always reply with `@` makes easy to get back

Comment: @AshishChoudhary it's displaying my two id in the array. Item: 1
Item: 2

Comment: @Dayan `{item.get('ID')}` no need to use get here... `item` contains a single object... use it directly item.name etc.....

Comment: @AshishChoudhary still nothing showing. now in the console.log it's showing undefined

Comment: you need to little work over it... I cannot do anything untill I look the code